# Как создать div с класом по первой букве елемента массива?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как пройтись по массиву объектов и попутно создавать див с названием которое равно первой буквы элемента массива. А если див с таким названием существует то просто вставить элемент в этот див.

сам массив :

```js
var obj = [{
  name: "banan"
}, {
  name: "ananas"
}, {
name: "arbuz"
},{
  name: "grusha"
}]
```

должно получиться примерно так :

```html
<div class="a">
  <div>arbus</div>
  <div>ananas</div>
</div>
<div class="b">
  <div>banan</div>
</div>
<div class="g">
  <div>grusha</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [функцией `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) для группировки

```js
var obj = [{
  name: "banan"
}, {
  name: "ananas"
}, {
  name: "arbuz"
}, {
  name: "grusha"
}];

function createGroupDiv(c) {
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.className = c;
  return div;
}

function createItemDiv(text) {
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.textContent = text;
  return div;
}
document.body.appendChild(obj.reduce(function(acc, el) {
  var g = el.name[0];
  if (!acc.g[g]) {
    acc.g[g] = createGroupDiv(g);
    acc.res.appendChild(acc.g[g]);
  }

  acc.g[g].appendChild(createItemDiv(el.name));
  return acc;
}, {
  g: {},
  res: document.createDocumentFragment()
}).res);
```

```css
.a {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.b {
  background-color: green;
}
.g {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj = [{
  name: "banan"
}, {
  name: "ananas"
}, {
name: "arbuz"
},{
  name: "grusha"
}]

var container = $('#container');
$.each(obj, function(i, e) {
    var div = container.find('.' + e.name[0]);
    if(div.length)
      div.append('<div>'+ e.name +'</div>');
    else
      container.append('<div class='+ e.name[0] +'><div>'+ e.name +'</div></div>');
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;  
}

#container div {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

С добавкой сортировки

```js
$(function() {
  var obj = [{
    name: "banan"
  }, {
    name: "ananas"
  }, {
    name: "arbuz"
  }, {
    name: "grusha"
  }];

  obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.name[0] > b.name[0]
  })

  var app = $('.app');

  obj.map(function(el, i) {
    if ($('.' + el.name[0]).length) {
      console.log('ecnm');
    } else {
      app.append('<div class=' + el.name[0] + '></div>');
    }

    $('.' + el.name[0]).append('<div>' + el.name + '</div>')
  });

});
```

```css
.a {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.b {
  background-color: green;
}
.g {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app"></div>
```